# Why do entries in the host file create new SessionIDs for each request

Tags: asp.net, iis, session-state

I am working on an update to one of our sites. This version will have unique behaviors based on the host name in the request. In order to test this behavior, I modified my computers host file by adding entries that point back to my computer.

```
127.0.0.1       newhostname.sample.com
127.0.0.1       oldhostname.sample.com
```

Everything seemed to be working fine, until I started working with the Session object. I discovered that after each request all my session variables were lost. Further investigation revealed that each response from the server contained a new SessionID.

**Why is that?**

I was able to hard code some flags to complete my testing using 'localhost' for requests without any problems.

Comment: Are you saying that newhostname.sample.com and oldhostname.sample.com are host headers on the same site?

Comment: Yes, both on my development box and in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain it, but I have an acceptable work around to my own problem.

Rather than use 127.0.0.1 in the Host file I am using my local IP. So requests to the names in my host file are handled locally and I keep the same SessionID throughout the site.

If anyone else can explain I'd be happy to know what IIS (or asp.net) is doing when using 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with the domain of the site and the session cookie passed - the browser won't pass a cookie sent to it from oldhostname.sample.com to newhostname.sample.com.

To fix this, you'll need to set the domain of the session cookie that is sent. This question should show how to do this - [ASP.NET Session Cookies - specifying the base domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326521/asp-net-session-cookies-specifying-the-base-domain).

Alternatively, you could look into using cookie-less sessions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx

Comment: Thanks John. Perhaps my question wasn't clear enough because of the multiple lines in the host sample, but I wasn't moving from one name to another. All requests were on either oldhostname.sample.com or newhostname.sample.com.
In production we are using the StateServer for our sessionState and this is a local problem, so cookie-less isn't an option I can switch to. I could make a modification for testing purpose, but that doesn't answer the main question - why was the SessionId being resigned?
That said, I will try to do some testing with a domain specified.