# .ASPXAUTH and .ASPXANONYMOUS are getting deleted in debug environment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, profile, membership

I am debugging my project at my local machine. I am storing information in two default cookies .ASPXAUTH and .ASPXANONYMOUS. However, I realise they are deleted everytime when I stop debugging. So SQL server can never match up the previous profile settings.

I read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240908/aspxanonymous-cookie-getting-overwritten-on-every-fresh-session) it says these cookies are only working when you get a real IP address.I do not have a .net+SQL server that I can use for upload testing. Question is, can I preserve the cookies or somehow make it work in my local machine? Thanks

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" defaultUrl="~/Home/Index" loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn"
         protection="All" cookieless="AutoDetect" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="8760" />
</authentication>

<anonymousIdentification cookieName=".ASPXANONYMOUS" cookieProtection="All" cookieless="AutoDetect"
         enabled="true" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieTimeout="8760" />
```

EDIT: To get an idea of the problem please see this pic below.
Instead of just keep using first row as UserId, the .NET membership keeps creating new entry everytime when I stop/start a new debugging. Reason is the old cookies in last session was deleted as soon as debugging was stopped.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to verify if the delete browsing history is not checked fro your internet options. If that`s checked, it might be deleting the cookies.